# Cannot find connected divices. Emulator start failed

Tags: angular, nativescript

I run this command in cmd as an administrator (Windows key > type "cmd" > right click > Run as Administrator).

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

I created first project on [NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction).

1. `tns create`
   -name ns-ng-course
   -style Angular
   -template Hello World
2. `cd ns-ng-course`
3. `tns run android --bundle`

But I get an error "Cannot find connected divices. Emulator start failed ..." 
`tns doctor` shows that "No issues were detected". I try connect my cell-phon by wire but it not helps. What do I need to do? 
My OS is Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (64x) 
 Thanks in advance.[image][image][image]

Comment: Just to check, did you install the Android SDK?  It can't find adb (it's all in the message).  Also, you need to have developer mode and USB debugging enabled on your phone.

Comment: Have you accepted "Trust this computer" on your mobile phone when you connected your device?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try

> tns device android/ios --available-devices

It shows list of devices connected. If no Device or Emulator connected

2. check that you have installed:

> ANDROID-SDK

3. check connected devices:

> adb devices

4. create Emulator using:

> AVD manager

5. Retry

> tns device android --available-devices

Comment: I tried it, and got this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/na0031)
What now I need to do ?

Comment: Device is connected but You need to check that USB Debugging Enabled or not
Have you enabled USB debugging in Android Device ? if no, (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

Comment: I did this , and turned on USB debugging.
"To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom."
But I do not understand why need to connect my phone for development, why not enough emulator. My phone is Lenovo 2010, an emulator Nexus 5x API 27. Maybe there is a problem here.

Comment: How to uninstall all correctly after install NativeScript? Plese help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while working in angular native script. when I tried to run the app
using tns run android command following errors shown

Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with

Fix worked for me as follows.
Android Mobile
Developer mode ->enabled.
Usb debugging -> enabled.